# WPF hierarchical triggers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, triggers

Is it possible to write a custom trigger in WPF that could be evaluated hierarchically?

**Update**: In this example I have used themes, but based on the initial comments it seems like I have to clarify that I am **not** asking for ways to implement theme support in WPF - it is writing custom triggers and the abstract concept of a hierarchical trigger that is of interest here, as an alternative to `MultiTrigger`

In code you would write

```
if (theme == Themes.Black){
    if (IsMouseOver)
       Background = Brushes.Cyan;
    if (IsSelected)
       Background = Brushes.Red;
}
if (theme == Themes.White){
    if (IsMouseOver)
       Background = Brushes.Black;
    if (IsSelected)
       Background = Brushes.Grey;
}
```

However when expressing this kind of logic with triggers you have to create a set of `MultiTriggers`

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="Theme" Value="Black">
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
</MultiTrigger>
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="Theme" Value="White">
        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
</MultiTrigger>
// And so on...
```

This quickly turns unmanageable for complex controls, so I tried to picture a way to prettify this, and came up with an idea for the following syntax:

```
<HierarchicalTrigger Property="Theme" Value="Black">
    <HierarchicalTrigger.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
         </Trigger>
    </HierarchicalTrigger.Triggers>
</HierarchicalTrigger> 

<HierarchicalTrigger Property="Theme" Value="White">
    <HierarchicalTrigger.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Grey" />
         </Trigger>
    </HierarchicalTrigger.Triggers>
</HierarchicalTrigger>
```

Does anyone know if such a trigger can be written, and/or have any tips on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Is offering themes what you are actually attempting to do, or was that just for an example?

Comment: Just an example, this could be used for anything

Comment: WPF does have the concept of "theme", you can declare color or brush resources per theme, and then use those resources as needed in triggers/other style setters. Have you done any research into themes in WPF? If so, please be more specific about why that approach does not work for you in your case. If not, you should do that research before asking the question.

Comment: Good Question!!!! I would like to get notified when you get an answer. Please notify me if you have any answers.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This question has got nothing to with themes at all, it's the abstract concept of a hierarchicaltrigger that is interesing here, not how to swap colors :)

Comment: You can extend System.Windows.TriggerBase or System.Windows.MultiTrigger (derived from TriggerBase).  MSDN has many articles on this topic.

Comment: Okay, fine. You still need to explain why the techniques involved in implementing themes in WPF don't apply here. The theme example is not useful, since that's not how you'd implement this type of logic using themes in WPF. But non-theme scenarios would work the same (i.e. not as you've shown here). The question is still too broad and shows no evidence that you've made any attempt to come up with a solution yourself. The obvious solution is to just put the logic in a view model somewhere, exposing the output values as bound properties. Why doesn't that work for you? Please improve the question

Comment: Your MultiTrigger approach is straightforward and the one to go.

Comment: @PeterDuniho really I wanted to know if it was possible to make custom triggers, and it seems like it is not (not usable in styles anyway). Obviously this can be solved with a view model, but thats totally besides the point. The core question was 'is it possible to write custom triggers' and the answer seems to be 'no'. Unless you've got anything interesting to share lets leave it at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go ahead and provide an answer:

No it's not possible.

Anything that goes in `<Triggers>` needs to inherit from `TriggerBase`. [Taking a look at it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/TriggerBase.cs,b3cd31e6b6e72c45) you'll see that the most important virtual methods (`GetCurrentState()` and `Seal()`) are internal so you'll not be able to modify that behavior unless you're Microsoft.

Comment: There is this, though... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff725477(v=expression.40).aspx, in the System.Windows.Interactivity namespace. But I am not sure if this is something which could have been used...

Comment: there's a difference between https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.triggerbase(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726552(v=expression.40).aspx and where they can be used. Just look at the inheritance hierarchy and read the pages.

Comment: Yep, and it seems like interactivity triggers can not be used in styles, so I suppose that's it. Thanks